# Verifying duplicate objects in array of objects using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am having array of objects in a following form,

```
let test = [
{
 RowCreationMethod: "excel",
 deviceID: "123ECd9",
 deviceName: "ZENW42NLPC0378",
 devicePrimary: "Yes",
 deviceType: "Laptop",
 employeeID: 101,
 isExists: "No",
 isRescheduled: "No",
 vipUser: "Yes"
 },{
 RowCreationMethod: "excel",
 deviceName: "ZENW42NLPC0378",
 devicePrimary: "Yes",
 deviceType: "Laptop",
 deviceID: "123ECd9",
 employeeID: 101,
 isExists: "No",
 isRescheduled: "No",
 vipUser: "Yes"
 }];
```

I have written following code to check if their exits any duplicate object in my array its working but if I changes the sequence of any object properties then its not working, because in my code I am converting objects to string and verifying it.

Here is my code

```
let final = []
test.forEach(x => {
  if(!final.some(y => JSON.stringify(y) === JSON.stringify(x))){
    final.push(x)
  }
})
```

Comment: you could probably use `JSON.stringify(Object.values(y).sort())`. Worst-case: loop though the object properties and compare each to each. If you do that, run your existing JSON compare and sub-iterate only if false to keep it fast when possible.  You can also use [].filter instead of forEach to collect the uniques w/o [].push().

Comment: You can use `Object.keys()` to get an array of the keys in the objects.  You can check if the array lengths are equal, and then check if their values in both objects match.

Comment: Will all the objects have the same set of keys or can they be missing?

Comment: all the objects are having same set of key but sequence in object is not same its random.

Answer (score 1):

For checking shallow equality, you can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys of both objects, compare their lengths, and then check if each value is equal.

```js
let test = [
{
 RowCreationMethod: "excel",
 deviceID: "123ECd9",
 deviceName: "ZENW42NLPC0378",
 devicePrimary: "Yes",
 deviceType: "Laptop",
 employeeID: 101,
 isExists: "No",
 isRescheduled: "No",
 vipUser: "Yes"
 },{
 RowCreationMethod: "excel",
 deviceName: "ZENW42NLPC0378",
 devicePrimary: "Yes",
 deviceType: "Laptop",
 deviceID: "123ECd9",
 employeeID: 101,
 isExists: "No",
 isRescheduled: "No",
 vipUser: "Yes"
 }];
 let final = [];
test.forEach(x => {
  if(!final.some(y => objectShallowEquals(x,y))){
    final.push(x);
  }
});
console.log(final);
function objectShallowEquals(obj1, obj2){
  const keys = Object.keys(obj1);
  const keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);
  if(keys.length != keys2.length) return false;
  for(const key of keys){
   if(!(key in obj2) || obj1[key] !== obj2[key])return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

If you aren't too worried about performance, you can use JSON.stringify on the entries of each object after sorting to compare them.

```js
let test = [
{
 RowCreationMethod: "excel",
 deviceID: "123ECd9",
 deviceName: "ZENW42NLPC0378",
 devicePrimary: "Yes",
 deviceType: "Laptop",
 employeeID: 101,
 isExists: "No",
 isRescheduled: "No",
 vipUser: "Yes"
 },{
 RowCreationMethod: "excel",
 deviceName: "ZENW42NLPC0378",
 devicePrimary: "Yes",
 deviceType: "Laptop",
 deviceID: "123ECd9",
 employeeID: 101,
 isExists: "No",
 isRescheduled: "No",
 vipUser: "Yes"
 }];
 let final = [];
test.forEach(x => {
  if(!final.some(y => 
JSON.stringify(Object.entries(y).sort())===JSON.stringify(Object.entries(x).sort())
)) {
    final.push(x);
  }
});
console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of every key in the array. Then, use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group the array based on a unique *value string* for the each object. i.e. a string with the values of an object separated by `|` **in the same order** as `allKeys`. For example, for the given 2 objects, it will look like this:

```
"excel|123ECd9|ZENW42NLPC0378|Yes|Laptop|101|No|No|Yes"
```

If another object has the same string, it will be overwritten in the accumulator object.

This will work even if some objects have missing keys

```js
var test=[{RowCreationMethod:"excel",deviceID:"123ECd9",deviceName:"ZENW42NLPC0378",devicePrimary:"Yes",deviceType:"Laptop",employeeID:101,isExists:"No",isRescheduled:"No",vipUser:"Yes"},{RowCreationMethod:"excel",deviceName:"ZENW42NLPC0378",devicePrimary:"Yes",deviceType:"Laptop",deviceID:"123ECd9",employeeID:101,isExists:"No",isRescheduled:"No",vipUser:"Yes"}];

function uniqueObjects(array) {
  const set = new Set(array.flatMap(Object.keys)),
        allKeys = Array.from(set);
        
  const group = array.reduce((acc, o) => {
    const unique = allKeys.map(k => o[k]).join('|');
    acc[unique] = o;
    return acc
  }, {})
  
  return Object.values(group)
}

console.log(uniqueObjects(test))
```

If every object has the same set of keys, you can skip the `Set` step and replace it with

```
const allKeys = Object.keys(array[0])
```